Creating an SSL certificate for Nest.js app
I am deploying a simple hello world app to AWS Fargate. When I access the public IP, the hello world message is displayed, but the connection is not secure. To secure this connection, I need to add an SSL certificate to my Nest.js app. Following is the main.ts file of my Nest.js app:
import { NestFactory } from '@nestjs/core';
import { AppModule } from './app.module';

async function bootstrap() {
  const app = await NestFactory.create(AppModule);
  await app.listen(3000);
}
bootstrap();`

Will I modify it to the following:
import { NestFactory } from '@nestjs/core';
import { AppModule } from './app.module';
import * as fs from 'fs';
import * as https from 'https';

async function bootstrap() {
  const httpsOptions = {
    key: fs.readFileSync('path/to/private/key.pem'),
    cert: fs.readFileSync('path/to/certificate/cert.pem'),
  };

  const app = await NestFactory.create(AppModule, { httpsOptions });
  await app.listen(443);
}
bootstrap();


Every deployment, auto-scaling event, or container failure recovery, is going to cause the  IP address to change. Directly accessing the app via IP address is not really a long-term solution. Also, you need a domain name for an SSL certificate, not just an IP address. You should consider placing a load balancer in front of the ECS/Fargate deployment. Once you have an AWS load balancer, and you have pointed a domain name at it, you can easily generate a free SSL certificate using the AWS Certificate Manager service.
